# Laravel assert status after redirect

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to test a simple controller:

```
public function testCreatePlace()
{
    $response = $this->json('post','/create/place', [
        'name' => 'Testburg',
        'description' => 'Hauptstadt Testlands'
    ]);

    $response->assertStatus(200);
}
```

But the problem is that my middleware redirects user to a subdomain with particular language version (e.g. `de.mywebsite.vagrant`). So when I run my test it gets the first status **302** and breaks immediately. How could I assert a request after the redirect, resp. obtain an end response status?

Comment: you could always disable the middleware. Laravel provides withoutMiddleware trait to every test

Comment: side note: I believe your status code needs to be `201` since it's an action of create